# cannot change uitoolbarbuttonitem color

Tags: swift, uitoolbaritem

```
func barButtonSelected(button:UIBarButtonItem){


    for vi in topNav!.items {
        vi.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }

    button.tintColor = UIColor(hex: "FF0000")

}
```

the func is UIBarButtonItem'action,I can change the tintcolor of the button which i taped, but can't change the others,the xcode shows cannot assign tintColor to "vi" error,by the way it's a swift code

Comment: tool bar items might be colored by the toolbar's background color. try changing topNav.backgroundColor. i don't have a project set up with a toolbar so i'm not going to test it myself right now.

Answer (score 0):

use downcast , check this code:

```
    func barButtonSelected(button:UIBarButtonItem){


    for vi in topNav!.items {
        let theVi = vi as UIBarButtonItem
        theVi.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }

    button.tintColor = UIColor(hex: "FF0000")

}
```